# Is there Hibernate API to check if databases were created?

Tags: java, hibernate

Using Hibernate, is there a way to find out if this was the first run where all the tables were created?

After this code, is there API (maybe on the `SessionFactory`) to get that state:

```
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(new File("hibernate.cfq.xml")).buildSessionFactory();
```

For my use case it would be enough if I know that one table was created.
So I can do other initial tasks, e.g. writing initial data into the database.

EDIT: this is the `hibernate.hbm2ddl` I'm using:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Comment: which hibernate.hbm2ddl are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

The following hibernate property may help you:

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files

This property specifies a SQL script that will run upon startup where you can easily query the metadata and branch on whatever business logic you need.

It's worth noting that the specified script is executed after the schema tooling has ran, so any changes based on entity models will have been performed if you're using `update` or the schema will have been created if you're using `create` or `create-drop`.